# How do I get Indy requests to show up in Fiddler?

Tags: delphi, fiddler, indy

Trying to inspect the header information being posted from my app but fiddler doesn't seem to pick anything up.

I am also using a web service in my app and when I invoke some of the APIs I can see these requests in Fiddler, however, when doing custom requests using Indy 10 nothing seems to be picked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Indy use WinInet?  If not, that's the problem.  Fiddler2 inserts itself as a proxy in your internet settings, but programs like SoapUI that use their own communication stack don't use WinInet, and therefore don't (auto-magically) pass through Fiddler2.  So you may need to mess with proxy settings.

Comment: I am pretty sure Indy 10 doesn't use WinInet (looking through the source I can't see anything). Do you have any idea as to what proxy settings I would need to change?

Comment: In fact, it's ok I managed to get it going. Just had to configure the proxy for port 8888 (as that's the port Fiddler listens on). Thanks

Comment: Indy doesn't use WinInet, but it definitely can be configured to go through your Fiddler proxy when you want it to. :-)

Comment: Thanks Warren, that's what I suspected.

Answer (score 2):

I use a construction to handle the requests in Fiddler:

```
try
  // lHTTP.IOHandler := lIOHandler; - even without this line works
  lHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer := '127.0.0.1';
  lHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 8888;
  sResponse := lHTTP.Post('<URL>', slRequest);
  Memo1.Lines.Text := sResponse;
finally
//  lIOHandler.Free;
end;
```